# adding fade on mouseover to images

Tags: customization, images, block-editor

I'm a teacher and I have been using blogger for years, but a couple of days ago, I decided to  switch to WP and opted for premium plan.
I'm not a designer, but am able to do basic things (adding custom css to a blogger theme, or changing html in blog posts) and I've been wondering if there is a way to add a fade effect to images on mouseover with css or html only, without installing any plugins? (for example - to masonry block as well as to specific images only)

Thanks!

Comment: Normally, this is easily done in css with `transition opacity`. How easy it is in your case depends on the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css in style.css or theme.css in your theme folder. also many themes allowing to add  css in theme options or Custumize section.
You can check css from here on image hover. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I used this code - grey on hover:
img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* For Webkit browsers */
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out; /* For Webkit browsers */
-moz-filter: grayscale(0%); /* For Firefox */
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out; /* For FireFox */
-o-filter: grayscale(0%);
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* For Webkit browsers */
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out; /* For Webkit browsers */
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%); /* For Firefox */
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out; /* For Firefox */
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}